# Read metadata of multi level nested embedded schema field(multimedia link)

Tags: 2011, templating, dwt

I am writing a DWT in which i need to read metadata of multimedia component added in a component. following is the component structure.

```
<content>
   <level1>
      <level2>
            <image>
      </level2>
      <level2>
           <image>
      </level2>
  </level1>
  <level1>
     <level2>
         <image>
     </level2>
     <level2>
        <image>
     </level2>
  </level1>
</content>
```

Here Level1 is a multi valued embedded schema . Level2 is also a multi valued embedded schema.

I am able to retrieve image tcm id as below. But I am unable to read metadata of the image.

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Level1" -->
    <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Field.Level2" -->
           @@Field.Image@@
    <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

I tried the below options to read altText field in metadata.
 @@Field.Image.altText@@
@@Get('Field.Image.altText')@@

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@@Field.Image.MetaData.altText@@`.

`@@Field.Image@@` gets you the Image `Component`. Once you have the `Component`, use the `MetaData` property to read any associated metadata.

Below is what the [**`SDL Docs`**](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-30CBA0F1-ED8C-4826-AF5F-3025EA8D7804) say:

> **`Component.MetaData.<FieldName>`**
>       The value of a metadata field of the Component called  (only use this construction if you have a metadata field called Title, Name or ID, or if you have a metadata field with the same name as a data field).

Check below, the various properties including `MetaData`.

[image]